# MVC5: Setting "Selected" property to true via a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 application, I'm trying to populate an IEnumerable of SelectListItems for a listbox, setting the "select" property to true via a simple query.  Here is the code:

```
GroupActivity groupActivity = await db.GroupActivities.FindAsync(id);

ICollection<ApplicationUser> attendees = groupActivity.Attendees;

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Users.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = c.Id.ToString(),
    Text = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName,
    Selected = attendees.Contains(c)
})
.OrderBy(q => q.Text);

ViewBag.Userlist = items;
```

In the debugger I've verified that attendees is indeed returning the expected collection of ApplicationUsers.  I've also tested whether this works for individual users with something like this, and I get the expected boolean results:

```
ApplicationUser yes = db.Users.First(n => n.Id == 1);
var x = groupActivity.Attendees.Contains(yes); 

ApplicationUser no = db.Users.First(n => n.Id == 2);
var y = groupActivity.Attendees.Contains(no);
```

This worked just find when user with id 1 is an attendee but user with id 2 is not.

My code also works fine when there are no attendees.  However, when there is even one attendee I get the error: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'SdNet.Models.ApplicationUser'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

My best guess is that the expression is not returning a boolean value on the contains query, although I don't know why this would be the case.  Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the EF cannot process the `attendees.Contains(c)` condition because `attendees` is not a collection of a primitive/enum type.

The solution is to prepare and use a collection of a primitive type (`int`, `string`, `Guid` etc., usually the PK type) like this:

```
var attendeeIds = groupActivity.Attendees.Select(u => u.Id).ToList();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Users.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = c.Id.ToString(),
    Text = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName,
    Selected = attendeeIds.Contains(c.Id)
})
.OrderBy(q => q.Text);
```